# ¿ como imprimir pdf con php sin usar librerias?

Tags: php, pdf

e visto que existen librerías ya echas  para imprimir pdf con php pero  tengo curiosidad  de saber como  imprimir pdf sin usar librerías,  me parece interesante y ademas creo que podría aprender cosas nuevas en el proceso. si alguien sabe de algún articulo o tiene algún indicio de como se puede hacer, agradecería que me lo comente.  saludos

Comment: Puedes iniciar con la documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdf.php. Ahí encontrarás todo lo que necesitas para hacerlo manualmente.

Saludos

Comment: te sugiero revisar la clase: http://phptopdf.com/examples/#pdf_from_html

Comment: es un solo archivo donde veras el codigo y entenderas como generar un pdf